# decimal to char coding

Tags: android, math

I am trying to convert a decimal into a character. 
I have my alphabet which has been converted to a charArray

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
alpha = alphabet.toCharArray();
```

I was using binary numbers so values only from 0 to 255, however when I try to execute this code, it does not work.

```
private int toChar(int encryptCode){

    int base = 26;
    int characterSteps = (encryptCode/255)*base;

    char character = alpha[characterSteps];

    return character;
```

Lets say I have the decimal 78, 78/255 * 26 would give 7.95 (being int rounds to 8)
It should look up the alpha array and give 'h'. But every character gives 'a' meaning that **(encryptCode/255)*base** isn't working as intended.

Comment: Doesn't `(78/255)*26` equal `(0) * 26`, which equals `0`?

Comment: It doesn't use decimals? How would I modify it to fit this

Comment: java101, chapter on integer division and conversion and promotions.

Comment: also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064281/automatic-casting

Comment: also, debugging tip: break your code into smaller pieces until you find where it does not do what you expect. (in this case, until you find that 78/255 == 0)

Comment: also `7.95 being int rounds to 8` is an assumption, and is wrong.

Comment: You are right, I'm not thinking straight.. Thanks for your help njzk2 and Kevin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin is right in the comments. Try rearranging your formula like this:

```
int characterSteps = (encryptCode*base)/255;
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually did "(int) (((double)encryptCode/255) * base)" and it worked as well, but your way is much better.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
int characterSteps = (encryptCode/255)*base;
```

to

```
int characterSteps = (int) (encryptCode/255.0)*base;
```

and you are done! 255.0 will cause broadening on encryptCode and base, and then cast to int.

> Lets say I have the decimal 78, 78/255 * 26 would give 7.95 (being int rounds to 8)

Casting float/double to int will result in truncation and not round off. 7.95 will be truncated to 7 and not 8. To round the integer, use this:

```
double x = (encryptCode/255.0)*base;
int characterSteps = (int) Math.round(x);
```

Happy Coding! :)